# swagger UI doesn't show apis while all configuration seems to be right

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have a springboot helloword project, the structure is[structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLxsC.png)

and my swaggerConfig is

```java
    @Configuration
    @EnableSwagger2
    public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket createRestApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                //.enable(false)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org/jayden/swaggertest/controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("SpringBoot and Swagger2")
                .description("desc")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }
    }

My controller is:

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    @Api(value = "testApi", tags = "test")
    public class UserController {


    /**
     * @param
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "user", value = "addUser")
    @ApiOperation(value = "addUser", notes = "addUserByParm")
    public String saveUser(){
        return "added";
    }
```

I use porm.xml:

```xml
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Could you please tell me what mistake I've made.
I've got the wrong message from swagger-ui:
[wrong message from swagger-ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9td0c.png)

I've got wrong message from console in chrome:
[wrong in chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amGt6.png)
This is my first time to ask question on stackOverflow, sorry for any unclear descriptions. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org/jayden/swaggertest/controller")
```

instead of

```
RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.jayden.swaggertest.controller")
```